# how to determine which composite manager is running

Tags: mutter, compton, composite

I'm using Arch Linux, and have both Gnome and the i3 window manager installed. When running i3, I'm trying to initiate the composite manager Compton. But trying to do so results in the following error:

```
$ compton
[ 04/11/2019 22:32:36.443 register_cm FATAL ERROR ] Another composite manager is already running
```

I think this means that Compton is already running, or Mutter is running, but I'm not sure which.

**Is there a command I can use to determine which composite manager is currently running?**

Answer (score 15):

You can use [inxi](https://github.com/smxi/inxi).

```
inxi -Gxx | grep compositor
```

The output looks like this

```
           alternate: ati,fbdev compositor: compton resolution: <xdpyinfo missing>
```

and you can see that Compton is currently being used as a compositor. With no compositor, there is no grep match.

Switches:

- `-G` Show graphics info (card(s), driver, display protocol (if available), display server, resolution, renderer, OpenGL version).
- `-xx` Show extra, extra data. (with `-G`, show chip vendor:product ID for each video card; OpenGL compatibility version; **compositor** (experimental); alternate Xorg drivers.

Comment: On Arch, install the [AUR inxi package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/inxi/)

Comment: Take note, for [some reasons](https://github.com/smxi/inxi/issues/158) not all \*actual\* compositors are going to be shown there. `inxi -Sxx` should do it instead (even though, at least without wmctrl installed, it is simply a lookup table checking running processes AFAICT)

Comment: @mirh `-S` only shows system info, I don't think that will show any additional compositors. I think you're right that `inxi` does not heuristically/canonically detect compositors, it can only detect compositors that it knows about. I noticed that `picom` is missing since the [rename of the fork](https://github.com/yshui/picom/issues/222), so I [added it](https://github.com/smxi/inxi/pull/213). Let me know if you noticed any other missing compositors.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have either Compton or Mutter installed, but the `xcompmgr` sample X composition manager doesn't bother to determine if another composition manager is running, but goes on and just calls `XCompositeRedirectSubwindows()` and handles the error that may be generated by it in the handler installed with `XSetErrorHandler`:

```
static int
error (Display *dpy, XErrorEvent *ev)
{
    ...
    if (ev->request_code == composite_opcode &&
        ev->minor_code == X_CompositeRedirectSubwindows)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Another composite manager is already running\n");
        exit (1);
```

This seems to be the only possible way to do it: [`XCompositeGetOverlayWindow()`](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/xorgproto/blob/xorgproto-2018.4/compositeproto.txt#L270) will always succeed and *map* the overlay window, whether it's already in use or not:

> `CompositeGetOverlayWindow`
>
> This request     indicates that the client wishes to use the Composite Overlay     Window of this screen. If this Composite Overlay Window has not     yet been mapped, it is mapped by this request.

**Note:**

Mutter is implemented as a dynamic library (usually loaded by gnome-shell), not as a separate process.

```
grep -sl mutter /proc/*/maps
```

on Linux will find all the processes that are using it.

Comment: So are you suggesting that I use Xcompmgr instead of Compton and Mutter?

Comment: No, I had just misinterpreted your question into something more complex like "how to determine if any composite manager is running on a display?" or "find the clients which had called XCompositeGetOverlayWindow". Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There is no command to know if *any* compositor is currently running, as far as I know. But you can use `pgrep` to know if a *given* compositor is currently running:

```
$ pgrep compton
18169
```

`pgrep` will give you the PID so you can terminate the process using `kill`:

```
$ kill 18169
```

Alternatively, `pkill` can terminate the process by feeding it the process name instead of the PID:

```
$ pkill compton
```

Some compositors (like Xfce's) may need a different approach to be deactivated:

```
$ xfwm4 --compositor=off --replace
```

Comment: `pgrep compton` seems to work, but when using Gnome `pgrep mutter` doesn't return anything

Comment: `pgrep mutter` doesn't return anything because mutter is implemented as a dynamic lib loaded by gnome-shell, not as a separate process. `grep -sl mutter /proc/*/maps` to find the pid of any process that may using mutter (or *something* using `lsof`, but I was never able to learn how to use `lsof`)